# Specific web pages won't load from within domain network

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Several months ago...my entire work domain network started having problems accessing yahoo.com.  The web page appears as though there is some sort of scripting error...i.e. pictures and news feeds don't load correctly and the site's navigational buttons (Mail, News, Sports, Finance, Weather...etc) all appear on the left hand side of the page as simple blue hyperlink text.

Then, about two weeks ago the entire domain started having problems streaming videos from youtube as well. The web page loads fine, but when I try to play a video...it "thinks" for a second or two then skips straight to the end where the video plug-in offers links to similar videos.

Up till now, I've been approaching this issue with the assumption that its caused by some sort of scripting issue with the browsers. So I started my troubleshooting by trying to access the same sites from within the domain using different browsers. Chrome, Firefox and IE all yield the same result. After that I tried clearing the local browsing cache, changing some scripting settings within the browser itself or, in the case of the youtube issues, updating/reinstalling flash player.

I am able to take my laptop home and view both web pages without issue. This has led me to suspect that clearing the DNS cache on my DNS/DHCP server might help but I am looking for advice at this point.

The general layout of our domain network is as such;

2 physical campuses each with their own 20mb fiber optic internet connection

Both campuses are protected by ASA5510 firewalls, each campus has an on-site DNS/DHCP server as well as a web filter server (Websense). On one campus...the servers all run Server 2003 while the other campus is running Server 2008 R2 on the domain controller and filter server.

The two campuses are currently linked with two T-1 lines that provide inter-site communication for file sharing and such. Eventually, these T-1 lines will be replaced with a site-to-site VPN portal set up through the ASA5510s on each respective campus. While this information may not be relevant...I figured I'd throw it in there anyway.

If anyone has any suggestions for other troubleshooting steps PLEASE let me know. I'm at a loss here and don't really know what else to do.

If you need any supplemental information about the issue, the network or the computers being used in the network please just let me know what you need to know and I'll be happy to provide what information I can.

Thanks in advance to you all!

Comment: If you bypass websense, does the issue still occur? It definitely sounds like a proxy/cache issue.

Comment: Strange as it sounds I've seen wonky web page issues caused by DNS. You stated that you cleared the DNS cache on both DC's but I'd like to ask you how you cleared them and also if you cleared the DNS cache on an affected client machine at the same time. Clearing the DNS server cache may not have had any affect if the client DNS cache wasn't also cleared.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean here, but your shotgun-troubleshooting is haphazard, bad, and potentially dangerous. You need to proceed ***SCIENTIFICALLY*** in your troubleshooting, and right now there seems to be no rhyme or reason behind what you're doing. Start with a clean, freshly installed workstation that is not on the domain & not filtered by Websense - Verify the site works. Move it behind Websense, test again. Join to the domain, test again. etc. . . until you isolate the cause of the trouble. Then you'll know where to look to find solutions...

Comment: I apologize for the errors in my original presentation of the issue. I didn't list my steps in order as I certainly should have. The troubleshooting steps I've tried are all pretty basic troubleshooting steps...none of which are "dangerous" in my mind. As I said in my original question...I have confirmed that the sites work on a computer outside of the domain. I've brought that same computer in to the domain...then it did not work. I've turned the Websense filters off...still doesn't work. I've had computers not joined to the domain also have the same issue....even if the web filter is off.

Comment: When I cleared the DNS cache...I went back to the same workstation, wherein I am logged in as a domain administrator, cleared the cache and restarted the computer. The issue persisted.

Comment: @Beeder have you removed your proxy or your internal DNS servers from the equation yet? This is really getting silly trying to force you to take basic troubleshooting steps to solve your own issue.

Comment: Is it really necessary to be so sarcastic, you guys? I posted a question to try and get help...not criticized. I'm not a professional at any of this...I'm trying to proceed with the steps that have been suggested. I'm told to start with a fresh workstation and attempt to access the site...it works outside of the domain. As soon as I connect to the web via the internal domain network...I'm presented with these issues. It doesn't matter if Websense is filtering or not. Do these steps not indicate that the DNS servers are likely at fault here?

Comment: @MDMarra, you tell me that it's silly to force me to do basic troubleshooting and yet I've tried what's been suggested...and you haven't suggested anything? How exactly am I expected to "take the DNS servers out of the equation?" I guess I'm just not leet enough for the badass moderators of serverfault. Enjoy your website gents...I'll seek assistance elsewhere.

Comment: @Beeder You remove your DNS servers from the equation by configuring a test machine to use different DNS servers. You remove your proxy from the equation by configuring your test computer to no longer route traffic through the proxy. Sorry if you feel put off, but this is incredibly basic stuff. How can we help you if you can't help yourself? Also, I'm not a moderator. Moderators have diamonds after their name.

Answer (score 1):

Install FireFox

Install an add-in like HTTPFox ( https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/ )

Go to Tools -> Web Developer -> HttpFox menu item, open in new window, and make the window bigger. Click the 'Start' button in the top left.

Visit yahoo.com in the main browser window, HTTPFox will fill with request details. Click 'Stop' when the page has/hasn't loaded.

Look through them - it will show you what Firefox asked for, what the server sent back, how much data, how long it took, and all the HTTP headers.

I don't know what you will see, but maybe some which aren't loading will stand out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, TessellatingHeckler. I'll see if I can learn anything useful out of it.